# Hive hql to Spark sql conversion

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to convert hql to spark sql .I am using below approach , with this I am not seeing much change in performance. If anybody has better suggestion please let me know.

hive-

```
create table temp1 as select * from Table1 T1 join (select id , min(activity_date) as dt from Table1 group by id) T2 on T1.id=T2.id and T1.activity_date=T2.dt ;
create table temp2 as select * from temp1 join diff_table
```

I have around 70 such internal hive temp tables and data in the source Table1 is around 1.8 billion with no partitioning and 200 hdfs files .

spark code - running with 20 executor, 5 executor-core,10G executor memory, yarn-client , driver 4G

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row,SaveMode,SparkSession}
val spark=SparkSession.builder().appName("test").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","/usr/hive/warehouse").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicit._
import spark.sql

val id_df=sql("select id , min(activity_date) as dt from Table1 group by id")

val all_id_df=sql("select * from Table1")

id_df.createOrReplaceTempView("min_id_table")

all_id_df.createOrReplaceTempView("all_id_table")

val temp1_df=sql("select * from all_id_table T1 join min_id_table T2 on T1.id=T2.id and T1.activity_date=T2.dt")

temp1_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2")

sql("create or replace table temp as select * from temp2")
```

Comment: you can try tuning spark hive configuration related to reading from the hive store.     
and one more point hive.default.fileformat is TextFile you can change it to other formats like ORC and can fine-tune configurations related to them and recreate tables against changed formats.

Comment: may be improve title of question